# How to log into AWS CLI with a federated SAML (AzureAD) login

Tags: powershell, aws-cli, saml

I'm connecting to AWS using a SAML login with AzureAD as my IdP. This is all working great and I can use SAML [response in the browser](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-cli-call-store-saml-credentials/) to generate a temporary session token that gives me an hour to work in AWS CLI. However, according to [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-federated-api-access-to-aws-by-using-windows-powershell/), I should be able to use AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell to capture the SAML Response but all I ever get is an error `Unable to set credentials: Root element is missing`. All my googling is leading to possible transient issues with certificates being near expiration or using older versions of the Powershell Module (I'm using the latest as of this writing: v4.1.13.0) or Powershell itself (I'm using 7.1.3).

Anybody successfully got the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell to work with AzureAD as an IdP?

Comment: What step is returning that response? Were you able to create your saml profile or endpoint? `Set-AWSSamlEndpoint` `Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile`. Do you need to switch to your federated role? `Use-STSRole`

Comment: It's dying on the ```Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile```

Of course I'm using the IdP init url instead of the AD FS one:
```$endpoint = 'https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/signin/*****'```

And I'm guessing even though it's the SAML module for Powershell, AWS doesn't support actual SAML login. According to this post they were "working on it" as of 4 years ago:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/d0650c99-4186-4fe7-bc2f-f616aabf4ff7/azureadaws-integration-way-to-enable-samlbased-federated-access-to-the-cliapi-using-azuread?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/39560995-azure-ad-aws-cli-authentication) somewhat more recent post, which has a ton more information about this kind of setup, some detail about how to configure it, and a note about why it may not be working (as of Jan2020)

Try using the `AWSPowerShell` command `Use-STSRoleWithSAML`[(AWS docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Use-STSRoleWithSAML.html) to generate some temporary credentials. The doc page goes into a lot of detail on what is required too for your Idp and in IAM, including links to relevant IAM guides. For example:

```
# Returns a set of temporary security credentials
Use-STSRoleWithSAML `
    -RoleArn 'arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTNUMBER:role/IAMROLE' `
    -PrincipalArn 'arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTNUMBER:saml-provider/SAMLPROVIDER' `
    -SAMLAssertion 'BASE64ENCODEDRESPONSE' `
    -DurationInSeconds 3600
```